# Add rounded edges to React radial chart segments

Tags: reactjs

I have a react based radial progress chart .  Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/base-react-circular-progressbar-examples-forked-x178l?file=/index.js)

What I'm trying to do is add some roundness to the segments themselves so that they have rounded edges.

I tried adding in `borderRadius: "10"`  but that didn't cut in.  Any suggestions?

```
<RadialSeparators
          count={20}
          style={{
            background: "#fff",
            width: "2px",
            borderRadius: "10",
            // This needs to be equal to props.strokeWidth
            height: `${10}%`
          }}
        />
```

[image]

Comment: The borderRadius didn't cut it because the progressbar is a full blue circle on which the white separators get put on, and you are styling the white separators. You could make the blue parts round if you find a way to make the white rectangle shaped separators look like a hyperbola.